# Spring Reactive in Microservices using rest calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I work on a micro-service project using spring boot web flux and here are some services:

- baseInfoService
- notificationService
- accountService
- orderService
- performService

I'm implementing a service in OrderService which would has this flow:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
//@PostMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Mono<OrderDto> createOrder(@RequestParam Publisher<OrderRequestDto> orderRequest){
    return service.createOrder(Mono.from(orderRequest));
}
```

here is my service:

```
public Mono<OrderDto> createOrder(Mono<OrderRequestDto> orderRequest){
    rule.validate(orderRequest); //returns Mono<OrderRequestDto>

    //====== in the same time after validation =======//

    //@todo call baseInfoService to get some data

    //@todo call baseInfoService to get some other data

    //@todo call performService and send orderRequest to get some data

    //====== after getting above request do ======//

    //@todo calculate and fill some order data acording above request results        

    //====== from here temporary I will use blocking style ======//

    OrderEntity order = transformer.transform(orderRequest);

    order = repository.save(order); 

    OrderDto orderDto = transformer.transformToDto(order);

    //======== after above calculation and save do these operation in the same time =======// 

    //@todo call accountService and send orderDto to serive
    //failure on this service is important and I should take proper action (there should be a call back instead of continue and sending notif)

    //@todo call notificationService and send orderDto to service

    return Mono.just(orderDto);
}
```

for now I should use webClient for services calls and in future I would use kafka and spring cloud stream and send requests as events.

- first question is should I use `Publisher<OrderRequestDto>` or `OrderRequestDto` in controller?
- second question: I have seen many simple samples existing in github and other sites but all just get a mono from repository and pass it to controller to return to user and I couldn't find a complicated real world example like this scenario. could you please provide the way I should implement it.

thank you.

Comment: Since you will implement Kafka or any other MQ/Event services later so for now you could continue with DTO in controller. on the other I would suggest you to implement each technology one after another, cause you might not found example of all desire technology together. So, better implement one by one and you will found those easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you use reactor you shouldnt call blocking apis, as you did it in the save method.
When you use webflux, you have a small number of threads and if you block those threads your application performance will be very poor. I suggest using reactive database driver instead.

1, You shouldnt use plane object in the controller, because you have to block the thread to get the object itself. In reactor, you mustnt call blocking operation. Also suggest to use blockhound if you are not sure about what is blocking. It will throw an exception during tests if blocking methods are called.

2, In reactive stream, you have to use the reactive operations, like `map`, `flatmap`, etc.. to do operations on your objects.

For example, suppose you want to go through a list of objects,  load some data from web to each and save those into the database (note that here I'm going to use mock db and webservice, but you can change those into real services and the essence of the example is the processor. Also I use Kotlin here, which is similar to Java)

```
//Mock repository
object ReactorDatabase {
    fun saveData(car: Car): Mono<Car> = Mono.just(Car(1, car.producer,car.type))
    fun loadData(): Flux<Vehicle> = Flux.just(Vehicle("Toyota"), Vehicle("Ford"))
}  

//Mock webservice
object ReactiveWebService {
    fun loadFromWeb(): Mono<String> = Mono.just("corolla").delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(100))
}
```

The processor function:

```
//Load vehicles
//Map vehicles to cars
//Load car type somewhere from the web and zip with the car
//Add type to car
//Save cars into database
//Return with the saved entites
fun process(): Flux<Car>{
        return ReactorDatabase.loadData()
            .map { Mapper.vehicleToCar(it) }           
            .zipWith(ReactiveWebService.loadFromWeb())
            .map { (car, type) -> Mapper.carWithDetails(car, type) }
            .concatMap { ReactorDatabase.saveData(it) }
    }
```

As you can see, all methods were called from reactive streams. When you use reactive IO operation, it always returns with a Publisher. You can use `flatMap`, `concatMap`... to get the object and push towards on the stream without blocking. Also if your operation does not block then you can call methods like Mappers from `map`.

With reactor you are not able to use imperative programming style (except using coroutines or similar struffs).

Also [here](https://zlaval.medium.com/reactive-spring-cloud-stream-in-practice-9c1e31ce8650) is an example to reactive spring cloud stream.

Comment: I have a situation I should wait for two services results and use current object and both results for my calculation. using zipWith makes a tuple with current mono and a service result, how should I wait for two services calls in same time (this is not sequential - if you recommend using a zipWith after another one)? if I need to continue after validation should I put all codes after validation in a flatMap?

Comment: In validation you can throw validationexception, then you can process that with global exception handler (for example controller advice) or use the on error signal in the reactive stream.
You can aggregate the 2 calls with the static zip method. It will waits until the two sources emmit a value and combine those into a tuple. When you subscribe to the stream, zip will subscribe the two inner streams simultaneously.

Comment: You might be looking for `Mono.zip()`. Be careful, if any of the publishers involved in that `zip()` are empty you won't get your tuple.